# After segue and dismiss VC I lost all outlet connections from main VC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem with the collectionView outlet. I have few VC in tab bar controller, and on main VC I have settings button with the segue to settings VC. This is obviously the settings VC has an impact on the main VC. But always when I try to reload data of collectionView after dismissing settings VC I have the error "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

I tried with ways to change VC (performSegue, present(VC), and dismiss) always the same result

mainVC

```
    @IBAction func settingsTappedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSettings", sender: self)
    }
```

```
    var query = false {
        didSet{
            GetPostsID(withQuery: !oldValue)
        }
    }
```

settingsVC

```
 @IBAction func ApplyFiltersTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let displayVC : ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        displayVC.query = true
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Error is in mainVC in function GetPostID `self.collectionView.reloadData()`
GetPostID is called in viewDidLoad too so this outlet works on first run app

I just expect to reload all data after change settings in settings VC

Comment: something is getting wrong in your code, not an outlet. Better can you please show code for viewWIllApper, viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the query of a brand new `ViewController`, which is not the same one as the one that presented the settings VC.

You basically need to pass data "backwards". One way to do this is to use the delegate pattern.

Create a `SettingsViewControllerDelegate`:

```
protocol SettingsViewControllerDelegate : class {
    func queryDidChange(_ vc: SettingsViewController, newValue: Bool)
}
```

And conform `ViewController` to it:

```
extension ViewController : SettingsViewControllerDelegate {

    func queryDidChange(_ vc: SettingsViewController, newValue: Bool) {
        query = newValue
    }
}
```

Add a `delegate` property in `SettingsViewController`:

```
weak var delegate: SettingsViewControllerDelegate?
```

Call the delegate method when appropriate:

```
@IBAction func ApplyFiltersTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.queryDidChange(self, newValue: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And in `prepareForSegue` in `ViewController`, set `self` as the delegate:

```
if let vc = segue.destination as? SettingsViewController {
    vc.delegate = self
}
```

Also, the way you set up your property observer could potentially cause a problem. You should use the new value instead of `!oldValue`, because property observers are called even if the new value is same as the old value.

```
var query = false {
    didSet{
        GetPostsID(withQuery: query)
    }
}
```